# Can't figure out how to make tunnel with tun interface

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, python, tunnel

I'm trying to make Layer 3 tunnel using tun interface between 2 Ubuntu VMs running on Windows in python.

Current configuration:

VM1:

- enp0s3 my main interface 192.168.0.105 (bridged interface in VirtualBox) configuration
- tun0 192.168.0.121 pointopoint 192.168.0.122

VM2:

- enp0s3 192.168.0.106 (bridged interface in VirtualBox)
- tun0 192.168.0.122 pointopoint 192.168.0.121

Python script I'm using: https://gist.github.com/glacjay/585369/b229da72a0dc84dd27d12afc5b76d0c5c44bb9c3
I also tried pytun (python wrapper for tun/tap devices).

So my main problem is, as I understand, that tun0 is not receiving/sending any packets to my main interface.

If I try to ping tun0 from enp0s3 (`ping -I enp0s3 192.168.0.121`):

1. On enp0s3 tcpdump I see ARP requests, 192.168.0.105 looking for 192.168.0.121
2. On tun0 tcpdump nothing.

If i try to ping enp0s3 from tun0 (`ping -I tun0 192.168.0.105`):

1. icmp requests on tun0
2. nothing related to this icmp requests on enp0s3

I've tried numerous ideas: route, iproute, iptables but failed, maybe because I'm not really good at routing and Linux administrating.

As I understand if something written on tun interface kernel puts it on "wire", and kernel puts incoming packets to tun interface. And other program should manipulate this packets. That's my goal, write program that can write and read on tun interface and make operations. But I can't start because I'm stuck on setting up tun interface.

Any help and ideas would be highly appreciated.

PS. Sorry for English, first time asking questions on such services. Usually I dig answers online but I've been stuck on it for 4 days now.

Comment: VirtualBox can use internal networking to connect each VM. Why not you configure internal Network in VMs?

Comment: They are aldready connected.

Comment: Can you verify that your two VM are configured similarly? Maybe routing is different between them? Try `tracerout`ing to the VM and see if any in-between stops are different.

Comment: @boardrider  tracerout 192.168.0.106/105 showing that these IPs are first hops. tracerouting 192.168.0.121/122 shows no resutls

Comment: Seems one of your interfaces is not working/configured, and maybe that's the NIC that you use for communications. Have you tried communicating via a different NIC?

Comment: @boardrider yes, it's my problem, that i can't configure my tun interfaces.

Comment: Your problem seems to turn into a non-trivial debugging work, for which -maybe SO is not your best bet. You could try asking on Quora or LinkedIn, or hire a freelancer expert (e.g., http://www.guru.com/freelancers/ronbarak/portfolio).